# What is the dimension of the span of a set?

Tags: linear-algebra

what is the dimension of the vector space spanned by the set of vectors $(a,b,c) $where $a^2+b^2=c$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach is to come up with vectors $(a,b,c)$ that satisfy the equation and figure out if they are linearly independent.

Note that in your question the dimension is at most three. Here, vectors (1,0,1), (0,1,1), (1,-1,2) are linearly independent vectors that satisfy the equation. So the dimension is three.

Answer (score 3):

It is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ containing the linearly independent vectors $(1,0,1)$, $(0,1,1)$, and $(1,2,5)$. Hence, it must be $\mathbb{R}^3$ in its entirety. The dimension is 3.

Comment: What do you mean 'the others'? $1^2+2^2=5$, so it must be in this set.

Comment: @user42493: Presume it is, so try to write $(1,2,5)=\alpha (1,0,1)+\beta (0,1,1)$ for some $\alpha, \beta$: you get a system of three equations in two unknowns ($\alpha, \beta$: $\alpha=1$, $\beta=2$, $\alpha+\beta=5$), which has no solutions.

Comment: I checked, and that should be your first impulse too instead of asking if I did.